# Detect Internet V. local lan connection

Tags: c++, windows, networking

Is there anyway with Windows api to detect whether a Windows 7 computer's network connection is an internet connection or a LAN connection without internet access?
Windows 7 and Vista indicate this in the network icon (Local only v. Local and Internet), is there anyway to grab that information progammatically?

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370750(VS.85).aspx describes the difference between `IsConnected` and `IsConnectedToInternet`. Windows 7 only. I don't have a native code sample handy, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the type of thing I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Pinging `4.2.2.2` is a common means of determining if internet connectivity is present.

The story behind this [lies here](http://www.tummy.com/Community/Articles/famous-dns-server/).

Comment: Interesting. What's vnsc-bak.sys.gtei.net?

Comment: Although now 8.8.8.8 is probably better (behold the might of google)

Comment: @Martin: Yes, though 4.2.2.2 is now muscle memory for me. I don't know if I can bear to learn 8.8.8.8 and its uncomfortable angle between index- and middle finger.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfectly.

You could detect if you are on a lan from the IP address (assuming your local DHCP handed out one of the 192.168.xx.xx private addresses.)

YOu could ping a known external site to check if that lan has an internet connection.

Comment: Just because the computer has a private IP address (which also include 10.x.x.x and 172.16-31.x.x) doesn't mean it's not connected to the Internet. As anyone accessing this site from behind a home router performing NAT can attest!

Comment: It wasn't clear what the OP was asking ie. direct internet connection vs NAT

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 performs DNS query for dns.msftncsi.com 5 seconds after link establishment. Do not see any reason to do that except for checking internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows API Code Pack will do this for you
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

its NetworkListManager Class has an IsConnected property that indicates if you have LAN connection

and an IsConnectedToInternet property that indicates if you have Internet connection

the pack download contains a Network Demo application that demonstrates this

Comment: the question is tagged C++ meaning native code. The Code Pack (which I love and am partially responsible for) is managed code eg C#