# C# checking for active modem connection

Tags: c#

> **Duplicate of**: [C# - How do I check for a network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520347/c-how-do-i-check-for-a-network-connection)

Hello,

VS 2008 SP1

I am using the code below to test whether the user is connected using either a wireless or LAN connection. i.e. that the cable is plugged in, or the wireless is switch off. The code works fine for this. However, if you can spot any potential problems with this or you know of a better way I would be interested to learn more.

However, the client would like us to check if the user is connected using a modem as well. As you can see from my source code I am looking for connection that start with either "Local Area Connection" or "Wireless Network Connection". This is ok.

However, the problem is that the modem name could be anything, as when the user sets up their modem connection using the 'new connection wizard' they can call this anything. So if my switch statement I don't know what to look for.

Any suggestions would be most helpfull,

```
// Checks if Network is either connected by LAN or Wireless
        public bool IsNetworkConnected()
        {
            NetworkInterface[] networkCards = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
            bool connected = false;

            // Loop through to find the one we want to check for connectivity.
            // Connection can have different numbers appended so check that the 
            // network connections start with the conditions checked below.
            foreach (NetworkInterface nc in networkCards)
            {
                // Check LAN
                if (nc.Name.StartsWith("Local Area Connection"))
                {
                    if (nc.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                    {
                        connected = true;
                    }
                }

                // Check for Wireless
                if (nc.Name.StartsWith("Wireless Network Connection"))
                {
                    if (nc.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                    {
                        connected = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return connected;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - How do I check for a network connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520347/c-how-do-i-check-for-a-network-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use the technique described here: [C# - How do I check for a network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520347/c-how-do-i-check-for-a-network-connection)

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

To monitor changes in IP address or changes in network availability use the events from the NetworkChange class:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged
```

Comment: Lol. Duplicating your own previous answer - that's a bit cheeky. :)

Comment: Why?  I referenced it, and thought it would save the poster a mouse click!

Comment: Well, it should really be posted as a comment with a vote to close as duplicate. It's also just milking reputation, given that you're not really producing a new answer. Not sure I really blame you, however. :P

Comment: Given that logic, shouldn't your answer should reference the earlier one? ;)

Comment: I've done as you suggested, edited as dupe and voted to close

Comment: @Mitch: I posted my answer before yours and also before I knew about the dupe. (I found the answer by browsing through the BCL.) Anyway, thanks for editing as dupe. :)

Answer (score 1):

The value of [`GetIsNetworkAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx) should tell you exactly what you need.

Description on MSDN:

> Indicates whether any network connection is available.
>   ...
>   A network connection is considered to be available if any network interface is marked "up" and is not a loopback or tunnel interface.

This means you can use it simply as:

```
var connected = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
```