# Live monitoring of network connectivity status

Tags: vb.net, networking, network-programming

A new client has recently asked me to develop a Windows service that will monitor whether or not his server has internet connectivity. The service should log when the connection goes down to `Local Only` and back up to `Internet Access` as shown in Network and Sharing Center.

My original idea was to have the service ping a website like google every 5 minutes or so, but I don't know how to retrieve the results of the ping, so I then thought I could code a WebBrowser control into it and write the log entries based on the results of connection attempts from that.

This also seems like a rather impractical idea though, so can anyone suggest the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working in windows, this is what you can try.
http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2557

For linux a simple bach script will do the job.

```
#!/bin/bash
WGET="/usr/bin/wget"

$WGET -q --tries=10 --timeout=5 http://www.google.com -O /tmp/index.google &> /dev/null
if [ ! -s /tmp/index.google ];then
echo "no"
else
echo "yes"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101041/capturing-network-status-change-event), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314213/checking-network-status-in-c) and...

Probably you may use WinAPI funcs [InternetGetConnectedState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384702(v=VS.85).aspx) and [InternetCheckConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384346(v=VS.85).aspx)

Correct declarations of them you can find at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread... Very old.. But hope this helps someone..

```html
    If My.Computer.Network.Ping("192.168.0.254") Then
        'online
    Else
        'offline
    End If
```