# Adding some kind of event listener for network connectivity

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, wmi

I have at my disposal the following resources:

VBScript, WMI Queries, Registry Key/Values, .bat batch files

Using any combination of these resources I need to create some kind of event listener that will trigger a .bat file when the computer re-establishes connection with a network.

I work in lab that constantly has machines changing networks and we are using BGinfo.exe to show what network the computer is on in the background image. So what I am trying to do is set up a listener that checks if the network loses connection and re-connects, then re-run the batch file to update the background.

How can I do something like `eventListener.on('connection', goIntoSomeCallbackFunction)`? If this is not possible using VBscript then is there an alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101041/capturing-network-status-change-event

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
dim shell, ip
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")


function main()

Dim status, result

result = False


'Here we have to loop every few seconds to look at connectivity
Do

result = statusChanged() 

If result Then
    shell.Run "D:\tools\Batches\updateBG.bat"
End If

WScript.Sleep(1000)

Loop While True

End function

function statusChanged()

Dim found, status

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")

status = False
found = False

For Each result in colItems
    If Not isNull(result.IPAddress) Then
        If ip <> result.IPAddress(0) Then
            ip = result.IPAddress(0)
            status = True
        End If
    End If
Next

statusChanged = status

End function

main()
```