# Axapta 2009 Determine Is Internet Connection Available?

Tags: axapta, x++

How to determine whether internet connection is available from X++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no AX function for this, so you must use [other means](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20internet%20connection%20available) to do that.

As AX plays nice with .Net the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085045/check-whether-internet-connection-is-available-with-c-sharp) may apply.

I can see no reason to check for connectivity, instead do the connect you want to do, then fail if you can't.