# How to test if Webbrowser gets a connection error when navigating to a new URL?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a PC that loses the Internet connection every 5 minutes. (long to explain why).
On the background I'm running a C# timer every 10 mins that does very simple stuff:

```
WebBrowser bobo = new WebBrowser();
bobo.Navigate(url);
while(bobo.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete){Application.DoEvents();}
string responsestring = bobo.DocumentText.ToString();
bobo.Dispose();
// and then do some stuff with responsestring
```

It is very important to make sure that bobo webbrowser DID have an Internet connection when it was loading the page. How do I do that?

I tried "try-catch" statement, but it does not throw exceptions when there is no Internet.

I thought of doing the "loading complete" handler, but it will make my program very complex and use too much memory, so looking for other ways.

My latest solution is:

```
...
while(bobo.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete){Application.DoEvents();}
if (bobo.DocumentTitle == "Navigation Canceled"){throw new DivideByZeroException();}
...
```

It works fine for bobo browser.
But when I work with responsestring - I create many other browsers (one by one) - and this solution does not work there.

Is there some other kind of test that I did not mention?

Solution found:
Thanks a lot.
I did not use your solution (it returns TRUE few seconds after connection is turned off).
But I found this:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool InternetCheckConnection(string lpszUrl, int dwFlags, int dwReserved);
public static bool CanConnectToURL(string url)
{
return InternetCheckConnection(url, 1, 0);
}
```

It literally sends a PING to the URL, and returns TRUE if answer is received, otherwise it returns FALSE. Works perfect.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "C# WebBrowser". There is a Windows Forms WebBrowser control, and one for WPF. Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: [check whether Internet connection is available with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085045/check-whether-internet-connection-is-available-with-c-sharp)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class InternetCS
{
//Creating the extern function...
[DllImport("wininet.dll")]
private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState( out int Description, int ReservedValue );

//Creating a function that uses the API function...
public static bool IsConnectedToInternet( )
{
    int Desc ;
    return InternetGetConnectedState( out Desc, 0 ) ;
}
}
```

You could also ping your ISP's DNS servers and see if you can reach them, someone on SO said that Windows pings microsoft.com to see if your internet is up.