# Knowing when machine is connected to Internet (Event)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, sockets

I am creating a Win Forms Application(C#). I need to keep it running 24/7 and submit some XML data when connected to Internet.

I am aware of few methods which keep pinging a solid domain to check if the system is connected to Internet.

But I am looking for some better or elegant way to do the same. I have some hints that I may be able to capture some socket events. Please help me with some ideas.

Comment: Try to connect with your socket and send data on success, you can fire some event also, but it does not matter, just retry connection and if connected send.

Comment: Do you want to *respond* to *a change* in network availability? In that case perhaps [NetworkAvailabilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged.aspx) might be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [How to test if Webbrowser gets a connection error when navigating to a new URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014295/how-to-test-if-webbrowser-gets-a-connection-error-when-navigating-to-a-new-url)

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll")]
private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState( out int Description, int ReservedValue );

//Creating a function that uses the API function...
public static bool IsConnectedToInternet( )
{
    int Desc ;
    return InternetGetConnectedState( out Desc, 0 ) ;
}
}
```

You can get more info about the function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks but this worked for me :) 


NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged)‌​;

Comment: That's handy too! For some apps, you might consider a combo approach - e.g., your app may not have been running when the network availability changed, necessitating an initial check before listening for additional events. Anyways, glad you found something that works.