# If statement for length property in C#

Tags: c#

In C#, if statement I am capturing the length property  and want to apply condition statement for that. But i believe my condition statement is not working. How should I apply condition statement for the given code. length "66" means internet connection is down else its up.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string value;
try
{
    value = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    value = (ex. Message);
}
if (value = "66")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Internet connection is down");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Internet connection is up");
}
Console.WriteLine(value.Length);           
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: You could change the code to `if (value.Length ==
 "66")`. But even then i would assume that it's not a good idea to rely on  the length of an error message (consider f.e. localization).

Comment: i just want to internet connection is down so when internet connection is down it always show "Internet explorer cannot display the webpage" this is actually i m check my Load balancer URl. I will get two results only one is empty html string or internet explorer cannot display the page. thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`value = "66"` is an assignment, not an equality comparison, which would be `value == "66"`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Actually, yes I would think so. (:

Answer (score 0):

if (value = "66") ->  if (value == "66")

Must return a boolean

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value = "66")
```

means, go to the statement, if the assignment of the String "66" to the variable value are successful

Jo need to use "=="

```
if (value == "66")
```

= -> assignment
== -> equal

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure this is a safe way to detect internet connectivity. When I try this code and pull my network cable out, I get

"The remote name could not be resolved: 'google.com'"

which is 51 characters.

There doesn't seem to be a property on WebClient to detect connectivity, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085045/check-whether-internet-connection-is-available-with-c-sharp?lq=1) might help.