# How to detect a cellular connection in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, network-programming

I'm working on a "regular" C# WPF application (no UWP app), and I need to know whether I'm on a cellular connection. Cellular connection being both when using a simcard inside the device, or when using a hotspot from a mobile phone.

How can I achieve this?

Background:
Since the application might download lots of data, I want the users to have a choice whether they'd like to avoid downloading on cellular connections or not)

Other SO questions:
I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501030/how-can-i-determine-whether-i-am-connected-to-wifi-or-a-cellular-network-wpf) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852810/how-can-i-determine-whether-i-am-connected-to-wifi-or-a-mobile-network-in-window), they're focusing on UWP functionality. Also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405895/how-to-check-the-internet-connection-with-net-c-and-wpf/25933213#25933213), which is just focusing on the connection itself, rather then whether that's a cellular connection or not.

Comment: By "regular C# application" what do you mean? Console app? Winforms? WPF?

Comment: Possibly helpful? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: It's a WPF application (I'll update the post)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb absolutely helpful, thank you! However it doesn't detect Hotspot connections from mobile phones. See also my comment on kyriakosio's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented with the UWP libraries and was able to solve it using UWP references.

I've added this reference:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17763.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\7.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd
```

And used this code to check for metered connections:

```
private void CheckIsMetered()
{
    var profile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    IsInternetAvailable = profile != null && profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;
    if (IsInternetAvailable)
        IsMetered = profile.GetConnectionCost().NetworkCostType != Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkCostType.Unrestricted;
}
```

I use the NetworkStatusChanged event to re-check the IsMetered.

```
CheckIsMetered();
NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += (s) => CheckIsMetered();
```

This works in my WPF app.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify your machine network adapters with [System.Net.NetworkInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Furthermore, you can take advantage of the property [NetworkInterface.OperationalStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.operationalstatus?view=netframework-4.7.2) to filter the adapters that are currently connected and [NetworkInterfaceType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype?view=netframework-4.7.2) to identify the type of connection. Check the example below.

Unfortunately I don't have a cellular modem on my machine to check if it returns the desired result, but try it and let us know if it works.

```
 NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
 foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in interfaces)
    {
        //Check if it's connected
        if (adapter.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
            //The network interface uses a mobile broadband interface for WiMax devices.
            && (adapter.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wman
                //The network interface uses a mobile broadband interface for GSM-based devices.
                || adapter.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wwanpp
                //The network interface uses a mobile broadband interface for CDMA-based devices.
                || adapter.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wwanpp2))
        {
            //adapter probably is cellular
        }                
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is absolutely helpful. However, it doesn't detect when I'm using my mobile phone as a hotspot (where for instance Onedrive immediately gives a pop-up saying syncing is suspended due to cellular connection.