# How to check if the user is connected to the internet wp7 ?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, connectivity

how do you check if the user is connected to the internet  ?
ive a program that uses services and i'd like to check first

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As seen on http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/12/09/checking-for-network-connectivity-in-windows-phone-7-sdk:

```
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{ 

}
```

Should be the correct way.

Comment: Remember that just because there is a network connection available doesn't mean that your app can actually connect to the internet or the site your trying to get to.

Comment: @Matt Lacey, does it means that if the user has the Network ON and no Wifi to connect that it gonna return True?

Comment: @Daok try it. My point was that you still need to consider connections failing even if you check for a network first.

Comment: This is network connectivity and not necessarily internet connectivity. IF your phone is connected to wifi hub then irrespective of the internet connection this would say that it is connected to internet ! Kindly verify !

Answer (score 0):

The phone api does not have a status for internet acces. You will need to actually make a call to test whether it's available despite the various statuses. See [What is the best way to check for Internet connectivity using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net)