# Check Internet Connectivity

Tags: vb.net

I need my application to check for internet connectivity on my user's computer.  If there is, an image is displayed and if there isn't, a different image is displayed.  Here's the code I used to get this to work:

```
    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded

    If NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable Then
        Dim bi1 As New BitmapImage
        bi1.BeginInit()
        bi1.UriSource = New Uri("Images\greenbar.png", UriKind.Relative)
        bi1.EndInit()
        Image2.Source = bi1

    Else
        Dim bi2 As New BitmapImage
        bi2.BeginInit()
        bi2.UriSource = New Uri("Images\redbar.png", UriKind.Relative)
        bi2.EndInit()
        Image2.Source = bi2
        MessageBox.Show("INTERNET CONNECTION NOT DETECTED")
        MessageBox.Show("You must be connected to the internet to use some aspects of this application.")
        MessageBox.Show("Please re-establish connection to the Internet and try again, thank you.")
        Me.Close()

    End If
End Sub
```

I decided to test this on my own computer by changing my default gateway (thereby making it seem as if I lost connection).  But I realized that the code still showed that I was connected.  So I'm thinking that it's only checking for connectivity of the interface - which in this case, is my connection to the router (which is true, I was connected to the router).

So, the question:  How do I check that the user's PC is actually connected to the internet?  I read the article [What is the best way to check for Internet connectivity using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/check-for-internet-connectivity) but it's in C# and I don't understand that.

Comment: @CodyGray.  I appreciate your comment, but I am now learning programming.  I am not a pro, such an insult is undeserving.  Don't you think?

Comment: Not really, no. C# and VB.NET are not all that different. If you're learning one, you should be able to figure out the other one. This wasn't complicated code to translate, and a simple Google search would have turned up one of the many automated translators. If an automatic translator can do it, surely you should be able to do it with a bit of thought and effort. I don't think someone should be encouraged to be helpless whether they're just learning or have been programming 25+ years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [this tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to translate C# to VB.NET or vice-versa:

```
Public Shared Function CheckForInternetConnection() As Boolean
    Try
        Using client = New WebClient()
            Using stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com")
                Return True
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

By the way, the [NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx) method you've used checks whether any network connection is available or not - **not** Internet Connectivity.

> A network connection is considered to be available if any network
>   interface is marked "up" and is not a loopback or tunnel interface.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  I'll try it and provide feedback shortly.

Comment: I tried to use the code you suggested, but i got an error telling me that "Statement cannot appear within a method".  I'm assuming this means that I'll have to create separate class file and call it in my method?  Please forgive the questions, I'm just trying to learn. I still want to be able to display the images based on the RETURN value, so please help me incorporate your code into mine.  Thanks.

Comment: @Kismet: Yes, the above code is a separate method that you should nest into it's own class(for example called `NetworkUtilities`). Then you could call `If NetworkUtilities.CheckForInternetConnection() Then` instead of your `If NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable Then`.

Comment: Thank you.  I've posted what I did below, slightly different from yours but that shouldn't be a problem right?

Answer (score 3):

Or use this code

```
If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
    MsgBox("Computer is connected.")
Else
    MsgBox("Computer is not connected.")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.Google.com") Then
...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](http://www.guideushow.com/code-snippet/function-to-check-if-you-can-connect-to-the-internet-vb-net-c/), which should help you out for VB & C# versions:

```
Public Function IsConnectionAvailable() As Boolean
    ' Returns True if connection is available
    ' Replace www.yoursite.com with a site that
    ' is guaranteed to be online - perhaps your
    ' corporate site, or microsoft.com
    Dim objUrl As New System.Uri("http://www.google.com/")
    ' Setup WebRequest
    Dim objWebReq As System.Net.WebRequest
    objWebReq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(objUrl)
    objWebReq.Proxy = Nothing
    Dim objResp As System.Net.WebResponse
    Try
        ' Attempt to get response and return True
        objResp = objWebReq.GetResponse
        objResp.Close()
        objWebReq = Nothing
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Error, exit and return False
        objResp.Close()
        objWebReq = Nothing
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function IsConnectionAvailable() As Boolean
    ' Returns True if connection is available 
    ' Replace www.yoursite.com with a site that
    ' is guaranteed to be online - perhaps your 
    ' corporate site, or microsoft.com
    Dim objUrl As New System.Uri("http://www.yoursite.com/")
    ' Setup WebRequest
    Dim objWebReq As System.Net.WebRequest
    objWebReq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(objUrl)
    Dim objResp As System.Net.WebResponse
    Try
        ' Attempt to get response and return True
        objResp = objWebReq.GetResponse
        objResp.Close()
        objWebReq = Nothing
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Error, exit and return False
        objResp.Close()
        objWebReq = Nothing
        Return False
    End Try


'Here’s how you might use this function in your application:

If IsConnectionAvailable() = True Then
    MessageBox.Show("You are online!")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will check network connection availability and Internet connection both :

```
If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then

    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.Google.com") Then
            Infolabel.Text = "Computer is connected to the internet"
        Else
            Infolabel.Text = "Computer is not connected to the internet"
        End If
    Catch

    End Try

Else
     Infolabel.Text = "Computer is not connected to the internet"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use Application Events to look for change in network access state, by implementing an event handler for network connectivity changed event in ApplicationEvents.vb, and there's an example for it in vb net examples that came with visual studio 2010 or so