# Network.IsAvailable always returns true

Tags: vb.net, networking

I'm trying to use the function Network.IsAvailable, but for some reason, it always returns true. I shut down my computer's wi-fi antenna and it still says I have network! (My antenna really is shut down, I've checked). Here is the code I used:

```
If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
        MsgBox("Computer is connected.")
    Else
        MsgBox("Computer is not connected.")
End If
```

If you have any idea why, let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check Internet Connection vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669248/check-internet-connection-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

Turn off you're Ethernet adapter also.

The code works; but I think that it just checks if there is a network device.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: yes its a answer to his question "I'm trying to use the function Network.IsAvailable, but for some reason, it always returns true" so most likely because he has a Ethernet adapter up. otherwise he would get false.