# Verify internet connection in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, internet-connection

I wrote this in VB.NET:

```
Function Net() As Boolean
    Return My.Computer.Network.Ping("216.58.209.142")
End Function

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        If Net() = True Then
            InternetConnection.ForeColor = Color.Green
            InternetConnection.Text = "OK"
        ElseIf Net() = False Then
            InternetConnection.ForeColor = Color.White
            InternetConnection.BackColor = Color.Red
            InternetConnection.Text = "KO"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        InternetConnection.Text = "KO"
    End Try
End Sub
```

How to check internet connection every minute? I tried using a BackgroundWorker but I don't know how to use it and my application crashed.

Comment: [Check Internet Connection vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28237131/1115360) might be even better for you.

Comment: My comment isn't a solution to your problem but improvement to your current code..
Why are you using ElseIf ? Replace this whole line with Else
Because that way you may call Net() Function two times if there isn't internet connection.

Comment: For your problem, Why don't you use timer ?

Comment: I don't know how to ask with timer to check the function each minute... but i think that timer is the ebst and easier way to do that...

Answer (score 0):

One of the alternatives is to use `Task.Delay`

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CheckConnection()
End Sub

Async Sub CheckConnection()
    Await Task.Delay(60000)
    Try
        If Net() = True Then
            InternetConnection.ForeColor = Color.Green
            InternetConnection.Text = "OK"
        ElseIf Net() = False Then
            InternetConnection.ForeColor = Color.White
            InternetConnection.BackColor = Color.Red
            InternetConnection.Text = "KO"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        InternetConnection.Text = "KO"
    End Try
    CheckConnection()
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. but Task is not declare (in error)

Comment: Task is a member of System.Threading.Tasks. Just import this namespace.

Comment: As  Imports System.Threading.Tasks ?

Comment: yes - Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Comment: Fine, but now delay is not a member of task...

Comment: What version of .NET are you targetting? Task.Delay works with >=4.5

Comment: 2017 with framework 4.7.

Comment: Task.Delay(60000) is with underline

Comment: for .NET 4.7 it should work

Comment: I tried to debug, but Task.Delay is still underline...

Comment: I've got an idea: is it possible with loop ?

Comment: Yes it is. What error do you get?

Comment: BC30456 error in debug

Comment: I found it! with time_tick ;-)