# How to fix my auto-updater VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Hello I need a little help in my project. So program will crash if it executes a code that requires internet I want to learn how can I command my app to check if there is internet then proceed if there is internet and prompt the user to connect to internet if not connected to internet

```
Public Sub CheckForUpdates()
       If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
           Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46370133/Noter/Version.txt.txt")
           Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
           Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
           Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
           Dim currentversion As String = Application.ProductVersion
           If newestversion.Contains(currentversion) Then
               Button1.Text = ("You are up todate!")
               label2.text = ("You may now close this dialog")
           Else
               Button1.Text = ("Downloading update!")
               WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46370133/Noter/Noter.exe")
               label2.text = ("You may now close this dialog")
           End If
       End If
Button
Button1.Enabled = False
       Button1.Text = "Checking for updates..."
       Timer1.Start()
       Label1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value
       CheckForUpdates()
timer
ProgressBar1.Increment(5)
               Label1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value
               If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
                   Timer1.Stop()
                   If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
                       Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46370133/Noter/Version.txt.txt")
                       Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
                       Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                       Dim newestversion As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
                       Dim currentversion As String = Application.ProductVersion
                       If newestversion.Contains(currentversion) Then
                   Button1.Text = ("You are up todate!")
                   label2.text = ("You may now close this dialog")
                       Else
                   Button1.Text = ("Downloading update!")
                   WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46370133/Noter/Noter.exe")
                   label2.text = ("You may now close this dialog")
                       End If
                   End If
               End If
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check Internet Connectivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800119/check-internet-connectivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.Google.com") Then

```
      MsgBox("Internet Ok")
    Else
      MsgBox("No Internet")

    End If
```