# Check for internet availability

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, networking, ping

I am trying to ping a if there is internet connection, hence I have decided to ping google as follows:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping("www.google.com", 500) Then
            TextBox4.Text = "Internet Available"
        Else
            TextBox4.Text = "No Internet avilable"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox4.Text = "Cable disconnected"
    End Try

End Sub
```

It is working fine, but the challenge is when i disconnect the cable, the application seems to freeze, maybe its due to the time wch makes the system continously ping. My delay time for the timer is 2000. Is there a better way to solve this problem. I will apreciate if u give a code or link

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to check for Internet connectivity using .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net)

Comment: Can't you just use My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable ?

Comment: Why are you checking if there is an internet connection?

Comment: I want to warn the users if there is Internet connection or not

Comment: So you are creating an app that monitors the internet, or is this part of another app?

Answer (score 0):

1. What Thread is your timer running in? These kinds of diagnostics need to be put in a worker thread seperate from the one running your UI. If you have not been using a thread, then do so now for your ticker timer.
2. You may also use the exposed Win 7 / XP API for checking Internet connectivity, just in case.

I hope this directs you in the right path.