# C# checking Internet connection

Tags: c#, networking

Can you please tell me if there is a way to check if there is a internet connection in my computer when my C# program is running. For a simple  example, if internet is working, I would output a message box saying `Internet is available`. else I would output a message saying, `Internet is unavailable`.

Without using the library function to see if network is available (since this doesn't check internet connectivity)

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

Or without opening a webpage and seeing if it's return data

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
      htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://google.com");
```

Because both of these above methods don't suit my needs.

Comment: what about pinging? it's less consuming than opening a page.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

a little shorter version:

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Another option is:

```
Ping myPing = new Ping();
String host = "google.com";
byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
int timeout = 1000;
PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
  // presumably online
}
```

You can find a broader discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net)

Comment: Using "google.com" will take more time because it needs to be resolved. Instead, pinging directly using IP will be faster. Pinging to Google Public DNS IP addresses (`8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`) works fine for me.

Comment: though Your code does not work in china.

Comment: I am combining both options.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the following code snippet...

```
Ping myPing = new Ping();
String host = "google.com";
byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
int timeout = 1000;
PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) 
{
  // presumably online
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Needs to be wrapped in a try block unlike other responses here. Ping.Send() can throw lots of exceptions which may include DNS lookup failure.

Answer (score 2):

just wrote async functions to do that:

```
private void myPingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
        return;

    if (e.Error != null)
        return;

    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
        //ok connected to internet, do something...
    }
}

private void checkInternet()
{
    Ping myPing = new Ping();
    myPing.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(myPingCompletedCallback);
    try
    {
        myPing.SendAsync("google.com", 3000 /*3 secs timeout*/, new byte[32], new PingOptions(64, true));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Especially for wrapping in a try block unlike other responses here. Ping.Send() can throw lots of exceptions which may include DNS lookup failure.

Answer (score 1):

My NetworkMonitor class now provides this (based on other responses here):

```
    public bool IsInternetAvailable
    {
        get { return IsNetworkAvailable && _CanPingGoogle(); }
    }

    private static bool _CanPingGoogle()
    {
        const int timeout = 1000;
        const string host = "google.com";

        var ping = new Ping();
        var buffer = new byte[32];
        var pingOptions = new PingOptions();

        try {
            var reply = ping.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
            return (reply != null && reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach;

1. Check that a network connection is available, if it isn't then we wont be able to connect to another host.
2. Check if we can connect to some major hosts. Use a fallback just in case that site isn't available.

   ```
   public static bool ConnectToInternet(int timeout_per_host_millis = 1000, string[] hosts_to_ping = null)
   {
       bool network_available = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

       if (network_available)
       {
           string[] hosts = hosts_to_ping ?? new string[] { "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com" };

           Ping p = new Ping();

           foreach (string host in hosts)
           {
               try
               {
                   PingReply r = p.Send(host, timeout_per_host_millis);

                   if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                       return true;
               }
               catch { }
           }
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```

Notes:

1. Don't use too many hosts when reaching out, weigh up the cost in time of making all the pings against the diminishing likelihood of success.
2. If we send the ping to a certain that host we intend to connect to later (eg a http request) a returned ping doesn't mean we are connected to that particular host. Consider what would happen if the host is blocked. eg Facebook is blocked in Iran,China,... Does that ISP return the ping?
3. A DNS request wont be sufficient as it may be cached

Answer (score -1):

```
public static bool HasConnection()
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.IPHostEntry i = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com");
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually can give false positives; The computer's DNS server may already have 'www.google.com' cached, yet has no Internet connection. Or; the computer's DNS Client service might have it cached, as well.

Comment: Obtaining target's IP is one thing and connecting to it is another thing!