# Check for Internet Connection, not for network availability

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, httpclient

I am working on a Windows Store app which is dependable on Internet. I am trying to verify for internet connection, I thought in ping, but apparently this class is not available in metro style. Note that I don't need to verify if the network is available I just need to know if I have a decent Internet Connection.

Does anybody has a workaround for this situation????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309158/c-sharp-checking-internet-connection

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net

I think you can find your answer in these links.