# Check whether connected to a Wi-Fi network or not C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any way to check whether the PC connected to a wifi network or not? Also, I want the SSID if it's connected. Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part for checking internet connection is answered here:

[C# checking Internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309158/c-sharp-checking-internet-connection)

The SSID part is answered here:

[Get SSID of the wireless network I am connected to with C# .Net on Windows Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431755/get-ssid-of-the-wireless-network-i-am-connected-to-with-c-sharp-net-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks! for the reply. I want to check whether it's connected to a network. There may be cases which the PC is connected to a network but won't have the internet.

Comment: In the first link you can see that there is a solution to ping. If the return from ping is a success you can be sure that you r connected to the internet.

Comment: I think there's some confusion regarding the question. I don't want to check whether the PC connected to the internet. Only to check it's connected to a wireless network. Turns out, the ManagedWifi can do this job. Thanks Aditya for the help!

Comment: o my bad i guess i jumped the gun too soon :)