# Check if connect to remote server by Webclient

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check if my project can connect to the remote server by Webclient in ASP.NET C# and do something.

here is my code

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);

if (webClient.OpenRead(url83).IsConnected) // Here, i want to check
{
    XmlTextReader reader1 = new XmlTextReader(webClient.OpenRead(url83));
    reader1.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: So you've shown some code (which calls `OpenRead` twice - probably a bad idea) - so what does it do, compared with what you want it to do?

Comment: I just only want to read XML from another site with USername and password

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net) best way to check internet connectivity might be something like

```
try
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url83))
    {
        XmlTextReader reader1 = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        reader1.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
        //Do something
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
     // occurs when any error occur while reading from network stream
}
```