# What the best practice for determine connection to internet?

Tags: c#, internet-connection

I should to check the connection to internet and keep that connection alive..
so i have few ways to do that, by using tcpclient or by using ping class..
and open new thread for that for every time slice check if the connection is alive..
what the best practice for that?
thanks!

Edit:
I see that have similiar question to that at: [What is the best way to check for Internet connectivity using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net)

But there the question is using WebClient that is slower than using TcpClient.. so it not the best practice for check the connection...

Comment: I would do it using `HttpClient` to download any known website, such as google.com.

Comment: i see that use httpclient is slower than using tcpclient..