# How to check internet connection availability on Service call using C#?

Tags: c#

I have 2 different async method with different return types. I want to check the connection availability globally between service call. But i don't want to check that in each method

method 1:

```
public async void method1()
{
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
   {
      HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("url");
   }
}
```

method 2:

```
public async void method2()
{
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
   {
      HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("url");
   }
}
```

thanks in advance

dinesh

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable (or a method) that both method1 and method2 can refer to and that variable can cache results of a connectivity check. As user1490835 commented above, you can use answer to [What is the best way to check for Internet connectivity using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net) to actually check for connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

assembly reference

> System.Net.WebClient

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
try
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
}
```