# Make my application logout if user connected to internet

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Can I identify whether my system connected to internet(not intranet) using c# or sharepoint without using ping technique

Comment: since the `netstat` command lists open connections, as does the Resource Monitor, there is an API, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this had been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net).

Using [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx)  to do a request or [ping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx)