# ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint blocks

Tags: c#, http, servicepoint

I am calling this method:

```
ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(mRequest.RequestUri, this.MapDataWebProxy);
```

for getting a service point, but when there is no internet conection available, the method just doesnt return.

Any ideas on how I can prevent this or set a timeout?

Comment: Use `Task`? And you can set a timeout?

Comment: `var task = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(input));
if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
    return task.Result;
else
    throw new Exception("Timed out");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to verify Internet connection before calling that method. It can be done something like this:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

    //Creating a function that uses the API function...
    public static bool IsConnectedToInternet()
    {
        int Desc;
        return InternetGetConnectedState(out Desc, 0);
    }

    public ServicePoint GetServicePoint()
    {
        if (!IsConnectedToInternet())
        {
            return null;
        }
        return ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(mRequest.RequestUri, this.MapDataWebProxy);
    }
```

Also Internet can be checked in another way. Without using of "wininet.dll" library: [What is the best way to check for Internet connectivity using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net)