# network availabitily in windows ce

Tags: c#

how to develop small app to windows ce ,to  know network availability in device using c#

Comment: by network availability do you mean if something is actually connected to the internet, is it connected to a local network, is it connected to a vpn? This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520347/c-how-do-i-check-for-a-network-connection

Comment: I've got the same problem, using Windows Mobile 6, I need to know if my device is connected to a network via Ethernet, Wireless, GPRS, VPN...
I can't find a way to do this.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

( i am copying my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784437/how-to-detect-network-type-on-win-mobile) here )

Look in the registry key `HKLM\system\state\connections`, there is are entries for each of the possible network types, for instance:

When connected to a wireless network:

```
[HKLM\system\state\Connections\Network]
Adapters="BCMSDDHD1"
Count=dword:00000001
Descriptions="Business World"
```

when connected to activesync:

```
[HKLM\system\state\Connections\Desktop]
Adapters=""
Count=dword:00000001
Descriptions="CurrentDTPTNetwork"
```

The `Count` value under `HKLM\system\state\connections` gives you the total number of active connections.

In `HKLM\system\state\Hardware`  you can find the current power state of the various devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpWebRequest`, and try connecting to Google:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=VS.80).aspx