# How to detect Network type on Win Mobile

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-ce, windows-mobile

I spend lot of time searching how to determine the current network type such as WIFI, 3G, Ethernet. 
But I cannot find any information online in windows platform.

I want to detect the Ethernet network type, but I cannot find any API that can retrieve the network type.
I've find Connection Manager for keyword but there's less information.

Did anyone have any idea?
Please help me...I was blocked by this for 2 weeks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the registry key `HKLM\system\state\connections`, there is are entries for each of the possible network types, for instance:

When connected to a wireless network:

```
[HKLM\system\state\Connections\Network]
Adapters="BCMSDDHD1"
Count=dword:00000001
Descriptions="Business World"
```

when connected to activesync:

```
[HKLM\system\state\Connections\Desktop]
Adapters=""
Count=dword:00000001
Descriptions="CurrentDTPTNetwork"
```

The `Count` value under `HKLM\system\state\connections` gives you the total number of active connections.

In `HKLM\system\state\Hardware`  you can find the current power state of the various devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API on Windows Mobile that makes it easier to access these values vs. going directly to the registry. See the [SystemState class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status.SystemState.aspx), specifically the [ConnectionsNetworkCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.status.systemstate.connectionsnetworkcount.aspx) and ConnectionsCount properties.