# Periodical updating data in separate thread (task actually)

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, .net-4.0, task

I've been considering what is optimal solution for implementing periodical (relatively long running) computations every `x` milliseconds in **C#** (.NET 4).

1. Let say that `x` is 10000 (10 seconds).

   Probably the best solution in this case is `DispatcherTimer` which ticks every 10 seconds. 

   In `void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)` function would be only code which starts `Task` (lets assume it would take ~5 seconds to complete the long running task). 
   `timer_Tick` would exit immediately and the task would be busy computing something.
2. What about `x`<1000 (1 second)?

   Wouldn't be there the big performance overhead creating and starting `Task` every 1 second? 
   If not what is the time limit for `x`? I mean: for some small `x` values it would be better to start one `Task` running for all the time until program does not exit. Inside created task there would be `DispatcherTimer` ticking every `x` second calling relatively long running function (maybe not 5 seconds but <1 second now; but still relatively long).

   Here comes the technical problem: how can I start the `Task` which would be running forever (until program is running)? I need nothing but `Dispatcher Timer` inside of the `Task`, ticking periodically every `x` (`x` is small enough). 
   I tried this way:

```cs
CancellationTokenSource CancelTokSrc = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
CancellationToken tok = CancelTokSrc.Token;
ConnCheckTask = new Task(() => { MyTaskMethod(tok); }, tok, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

```
void MyTaskMethod(CancellationToken CancToken)
{
    MyTimer = new DispatcherTimer(); // MyTimer is declared outside this method
    MyTimer.Interval = x;
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    MyTimer.IsEnabled = true;

    while (true) ; // otherwise task exits and `timer_Tick` will be executed in UI thread
}
```

---

### -- Edit: --

By intensive calculating I meant checking if connection with specified server is up or down. I want to monitor connection in order to alert user when connection goes down.

Checking connection is implemented this way (thanks to **[Ragnar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405895/how-to-check-internet-connection-with-net-c-wpf)**):

```cs
private bool CheckConnection(String URL)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Timeout = 15000;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? true : false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?   You have list of computations you need to perform (as a tasks)?   Or every x seconds you want to kick off a computation as a task?

Comment: I think a timer makes more sense for a repeating task.  I don't think the overhead of creating a Task would be all that great.  But, if you *think* is might be: test and measure.  If you don't know it *will* going into it, it probably isn't.

Comment: In the case of timer, you're running something on the UI thread--which doesn't require any new threads to start.  `Task` (with the default `TaskScheduler`) uses thread pool threads.  The more thread pool threads you use, the more you stress the thread pool. Yes, that's what it's for, but that's a shared resource.  e.g. if you have a long-running thread (i.e. longer than 1 second) the thread pool with start another thread to make sure it has a minimum number of available threads.

Comment: @Blam - I'm trying to implement periodical checking (monitoring) connection with server. Normally it takes relatively much time to check out if there is connection with server.

Comment: Then maybe update your update your question.  Based on the wording I thought you meant a compute intensive operation.  So you want to post an alert when a connection is down?   What determines connection down - no answer to a ping?   Post the code to test for connection up.