# Unable to use IPHostEntry class in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone, internet-connection, network-interface

I am making a windows phone 7 application in c#, visual studio 2012 and it needs to check if internet connection is available in the device before sending some request.

Initially I was trying to use

```
NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

but it always returned true.I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457407/why-is-getisnetworkavailable-always-returning-true). But I am now having problem with that also.

I wrote the following code(after `using System.Net` ) 
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5y1T.png)

```
    private bool checkInternet()
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry _hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("www.google.com");
            return true;
        }
        catch(SocketException _err){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But it didn't compile and gave the following error [Error_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/634XC.png)

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'IPHostEntry' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You sure you add `System` assembly? Not `System` namespace.

Comment: Yes System is included in references(in solution explorer) also...

Comment: Replace `IPHostEntry` in your function with `var`. You're not caring what it is anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Let me ask you a very deep question:

> are you missing a using directive?

This is a quote from the error message, and following up on it resolves your problem. I encourage you to do some research what a using directive is and what they mean in the C# language.

Comment: This is all the directives I have included -- [Code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/au8rn.png)... Please help me out, I don't see what is the problem here

Comment: Please also show a screenshot that you referenced the appropriate assembly.

Comment: Why is `system` with lowercase-s? Remove the reference and add it back. Not sure what you got there.

Comment: I added the System back with uppercase 'S' but with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you must use the

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation
```

namespace

which implements the [NetworkInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(v=vs.110).aspx) and provides your method.