# check network connection availability when application running

Tags: c#

I want to navigate to php or xml files those are in server, but for that I need to have Internet access.

How can I see if there's a connection available and ***active*** using C#?

Comment: Just try to download. Another option is to send HTTP `HEAD` request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - How do I check for a network connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520347/c-how-do-i-check-for-a-network-connection)

Comment: Now, **[that duplicate shouldn't have been too hard to find](http://i.stack.imgur.com/e25gD.png)**.

Comment: Hello, in that they are asking how to check internet connection. My question is how to handle if any network breakdowns occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the resource in question. If you can't then there's no connection "available and active"

Without more detail in your question, it's difficult to provide more info.

Comment: is there any options like event handlers to handle this

Comment: @deepika, of course there are, but you can't be helped unless you post more info about how you are wanting to connect.

Comment: I'm using c# utility that takes care of data synchronization of online and online process. In this utility when i'm sending offline data to online it requires internet connection. So that time i need this