# Same exception without network connection and with an incorrect URL

Tags: .net

I'm trying to catch an exception while doing:

```
myStreamRequest = GetRequestStream()
```

The problem is that I get the same error when my pc doesn't have a correct network connection (it is unplugged) and when the requested URL is not correct. The exception is `WebException` and the status: `NameResolutionFailure`, and I need to make a difference between those two errors. I've been trying to catch a possible `innerException`, but it is not thrown in this case.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the [existance of a network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520352/540345), before you make a request.

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!it works fine, i didn't think I could do something like this, I was trying to do a very difficult checking but this is so easy and so helpful!!!!Thank you!

Comment: @Doubting - You are welcome! Dont forget to [mark the answer as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Also, you can upvote if you found the answer helpfull.