# Can I do better than NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, network-programming

I have a .NET application that needs to access resources from a web site. Access to these resources may require the user to change their proxy settings.

I'm wondering how best to detect the presence of a network (i.e. potential internet connection) from the application in a way that is useful for deciding whether to offer the user the ability to change their proxy settings. If there is no network available that can allow a connection to the internet, then changing the proxy settings won't help.

There is [NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx), but this returns true

> if any network interface is marked "up" and is not a loopback or
>   tunnel interface.

I found that after disconnecting the network cable and wifi on my machine (Google could not be reached), this method still returned true and a number of network interfaces were still up.

- One had a type of Ppp which corresponded to a VPN connection.
- Another had a type of Ethernet but a description of "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #4".
- The third had a type of Loopback.

Obviously the test I performed was only exploratory, and could not be used as a conclusive means of coming up with some kind of filter. There is a suggested filter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345173/3051702) but in my test, this always returned false whether or not I had an internet connection, unless I was connected to the VPN.

I can't just attempt to access (say) google.com as this could also fail due to proxy settings being incorrectly configured.

Does what I am trying to do have a viable solution? Can I do better than GetNetworkIsAvailable()?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) in an [answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345173/146921), there are certain cases when the standard method is fooled by virtual cards.

He is proposing using `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` and iterate through interfaces checking for connection and ignoring virtual, tunnel and loopback interfaces.

I have implemented his solution and it works great. Performance wise you can skip his initial `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()`, as the rest of the code do the exact same checks. Both method is fairly CPU expensive, so running both is unnecessary.

I will not copy and take credit, so take a look at his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8345173/146921