# Detect internet connection on Windows

Tags: windows, api, networking

How can I determine if the Internet is available if it is known that there is a network connection?
Windows indicates that there is no connection from the Internet to the icons in the notification area. Is it possible to know this condition?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check for a network connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520347/how-do-i-check-for-a-network-connection)

Comment: Since you didn't specify a programming language, I assumed C# (.NET langauges).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access(HTTP GET) popular websites such as http://clients3.google.com/generate_204, then check HTTP status code 204